# How to retrieve an id from a tosql function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am inserting a lot of data into my `pools` table. At the same time while I am doing this I need to set my **isactive** field in the `draws` table to **0**. However I am having issues doing this.

**Code:**

```
        $pools = DB::table('addresses as a')
                    ->join('incodes as i', 'i.id', '=', 'a.incode_id')
                    ->join('draws as d', 'd.incode_id', '=', 'i.id')
                    ->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'a.user_id')
                    ->where('d.isactive', '=', '1')
                    ->select('u.id as user_id', 'd.id as draw_id')->distinct();

       $bindings = $pools->getBindings();

       $insertQuery = 'INSERT into pools (user_id, draw_id)'.$pools->toSql();

      $pools = \DB::statement($insertQuery, $bindings);


foreach($pools as $pool) {
 //Deactivate draw id from draws table when 
 //successfully inserted  in pools table

 Draw::where('id', $pool->draw_id)
                   ->update(['isactive' => 0]);
}
```

The `foreach` loop will never work with `$pools` because of the natural of `\DB::statement`.

So how do I set `isactive` field in `draws` table to `0` when it has been inserted in the `pools` tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$pools = DB::table('addresses as a')
        ->join('incodes as i', 'i.id', '=', 'a.incode_id')
        ->join('draws as d', 'd.incode_id', '=', 'i.id')
        ->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'a.user_id')
        ->where('d.isactive', '=', '1')
        ->select('u.id as user_id', 'd.id as draw_id')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

Pool::insert($pools);

foreach ($pools as $pool) {
    if ($draw = Draw::find($pool['draw_id'])) {
        $draw->isactive = 0;
        $draw->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I asume you through i had a  `Pools` model when you did this `Pool::insert` which you were right, if that is the case. Unfortunately I am getting this error `Call to a member function toArray()`. You have any other ideas please. I have tried removing the `toArray` call and got `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`. Thanks

Comment: Hi again Armen, I figure it out how to do it. thanks I just did included the insert in the forech loop but this will take a while due to the amount of data but i had to set php max time to 0

Comment: Hi Baako. Making INSERTs in a loop is a bad idea. I've updated the answer, please try it and let me know if it works for you.